# Dúvida sobre conexão PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

E ae pessoal, to com uma dúvida sobre a conexão PDO.

Essa é a conexão que tenho no script que to configurando:

```
<?php

function getDB() {
    $dbHost = 'host';
    $db     = 'bd';
    $dbUser = 'user';

    # Get database password from outside of web root
    $fileLoc = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../passwords.txt';
    if (file_exists($fileLoc)) {
        $fh = fopen($fileLoc, 'r');
        $jsonStr = fgets($fh);
        $arr = json_decode($jsonStr, true);
        $dbPass = $arr['default-password'];
        fclose($fh);
    } else {
        die('no file found');
    }

    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$db;charset=utf8mb4", $dbUser, $dbPass);
    return $db;
}

function getSteamProfileInfoForSteamID($allUsersInfoStr, $steamIDToFind) {
    $allUsersInfo = json_decode($allUsersInfoStr, true);
    $players = $allUsersInfo['response']['players'];

    foreach ($players as $player) {
        $steamID = $player['steamid'];
        $player['personaname'] = htmlentities($player['personaname']);

        if ($steamIDToFind === $steamID) {
            return $player;
        }
    }

    # If the user is not found, then return false
    return false;
}

function jsonSuccess($data) {
    return json_encode(array('success' => 1, 'data' => $data));
}

function jsonErr($errMsg) {
    return json_encode(array('success' => 0, 'errMsg' => $errMsg));
}

function getSteamAPIKey() {
    $fileLoc = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../passwords.txt';
    if (file_exists($fileLoc)) {
        $fh = fopen($fileLoc, 'r');
        $jsonStr = fgets($fh);
        $arr = json_decode($jsonStr, true);
        $key = $arr['steamAPIKey'];
        fclose($fh);
        return $key;
    } else {
        die('no file found');
    }
}

function postVar($varName) {
    $var = isset($_POST[$varName]) ? $_POST[$varName] : null;

    if (is_null($var) || strlen($var) === 0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return $var;
    }
}

function getVar($varName) {
    $var = isset($_GET[$varName]) ? $_GET[$varName] : null;

    if (is_null($var) || strlen($var) === 0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return $var;
    }
}
?>
```

Essa conexão ta buscando a senha em um arquivo txt dentro do root, mas eu não tenho acesso ao root da minha hospedagem, alguém sabe como alterar pra colocar a senha direto no código?

Comment: O problema parece ser o acesso(privilegio) do usuário a base de dados

Comment: Eu não tenho acesso ao root pra colocar esse txt la dentro, preciso mudar a conexão. Sobre os privilégios do usuário, ele tem todos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apenas remova o trecho do código que faz a busca e coloque manualmente os valores nas variáveis declaradas acima, e NUNCA coloque senha de banco de dados em arquivos txt ou arquivos que sejam lidos através do browser, é um erro fatal de segurança, sua função `getDB` ficará assim:

```
function getDB() {
    $dbHost = 'host'; // host
    $db     = 'bd'; // nome do banco
    $dbUser = 'user'; // usuário
    $dbPass = 'pass'; // criada aqui a variável para a senha, atribua o valor

    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$db;charset=utf8mb4", $dbUser, $dbPass);
    return $db;
}
```

Espero que ajude, abraços

Comment: eu ja havia tentado assim e me retornou o seguinte erro: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'@'10.1.2.39' (using password: YES)' in /home/u232474995/public_html/test/php/default.php:10 Stack trace: #0 /home/u232474995/public_html/test/php/default.php(10): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=mysq...', 'u232474995_user...', 'SENHA') #1 /home/u232474995/public_html/test/php/login-status.php(8): getDB() #2 {main} thrown in /home/u232474995/public_html/test/php/default.php on line 10

Comment: Verifique se seu login e senha estão corretos e de acordo com o do servidor que está tentando conectar